# Is $l^p$ closed in $L^p$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let's assume we have a subspace $X$ of $L^p$ and we know that $X \cong l^p$(this should just mean isomorph no isometry is assumed here). Can we infer from this that $X$ is closed? I have just read a few things that would suggest that this is true, but I don't see how this could be shown?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a purely algebraic isomorphism, or topological (though, as you say, not necessarily isometric)?

Comment: it is a topological one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it is a topological one.

In that case, $X$ must be a closed subspace. That is, because an isomorphism of topological vector spaces is not only a topological isomorphism, but also an isomorphism in the category of uniform spaces (with uniformly continuous maps as morphisms), so if $X$ (with the subspace topology induced by $L^p$) is isomorphic to $l^p$ as a topological vector space, it is complete, because $l^p$ is. And a complete subspace of a Hausdorff uniform space is closed.

Comment: thank you, but let's understand this: It does not depend on $l^p$ actually. So, what you are saying is, that as soon as I have a subspace of a Banach space that is isomorphic to another Banach space, this subspace is closed, right? The reasoning was that from the completeness of the other Banach space we can conclude that the subspace is a Banach space and therefore it is closed?

Comment: Right. Under the condition that it is a topological isomorphism, of course.